# Unable to Send Push Notification in ios using Mesibo

Tags: ios, notifications, chat, push, mesibo

Unable to Send Push Notification in ios using Mesibo, follow documentation but not succeeded

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide details. Do not hesitate reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You should provide details, merely stating "not succeeded" does not give us any information to help you.

Refer to troubleshooting steps here, especially for iOS https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/push-notifications/#troubleshooting

- Ensure that you are not using PushKit Tokens for regular notifications. iOS will terminate your app if you misuse PushKit tokens. Refer to Apple documentation and also WWDC talk Advances in App Background Execution.
- Use the Production Certificate, not the development certificate. Mesibo console will give you a warning but will accept the certificate. However, your device is likely not to receive push notifications.
- Don’t mess with the APS entitlements setting unless you know what you are doing.
  By default, it is set to development for the development and set to Production by Xcode when you upload your app to the App Store for release or test flight. This setting impacts the selected APN endpoint for sending push notifications. Hence, if you change this to say ‘Production’, you may need to send all your sandbox pushes to the production APN server

If you still can't resolve it, follow the debugging steps and post results here

https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/push-notifications/#debugging-push-notifications-using-webhooks